# position text on same level as image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a text in the middle height of an image, but the margin-top or margin-bottom would not work as I want.

Any tips on this?

I created an JsFiddle to show the work -
http://jsfiddle.net/HdW7Y/1/

As you see the the text Login User is below the login button.

HTML

```
<div id="topNav">
<ul>
<li class="topMenu-bg1 show_hide_contact">
<a href="#"></a>
</li>
<li class="topMenu-bg2 show_hide_login">
<a href="#" ><p class="icon2text">User Login</p></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#topNav li {
margin-top:5px;
padding-top:7px;
list-style:none;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid black;
}

.icon2text{ 
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 0.7em;
display: inline;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vertical-align` property on `.icon2text` and set it to top:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdW7Y/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add

.topMenu-bg2 show_hide_login{
valign:middle;
}

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the p tag with a span and remove the top padding from the li item and the top padding from the a tag it should all line up.